# Insert unix timestamp to postgres timestamp column (node-postgres)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm using node-postgres module and node 13.5. I'm trying to insert a unix timestamp to postgres timestmap column and it seems to work in dbeaver but when I run the code it doesn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (
    column1 timestamp NULL
);
```

In dbeaver when I run my insert:

```
insert into test (column1 ) values ( $1 )
```

It opens up a dialog I type in my param as: to_timestamp(1) I hit ok and it inserts to my table without problem.

But when I use this code:

```
pool.query("INSERT INTO test (column1) VALUES ($1)", ["to_timestamp(1)"]);
```

I get an error:

```
error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "to_timestamp(1)"
```

*the query method is the one from the module.*

Also if I run like this:

```
pool.query("INSERT INTO test (column1) VALUES (to_timestamp(1))", []);
```

It works.

It seems like the nodejs driver doing something different from the dbeaver driver. Am I doing this wrong? Is there a way to to approach this problem? I'd like to use prepared statement if possible.

The things I can't change:

- my data is in unix timestamp
- the column must have timestamp type

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My college helped me:

```
pool.query("INSERT INTO test (column1) VALUES to_timestamp($1)", ["1"]);
```

This is the working solution!